# How do I minimize the amount of code for a hierarchy

Tags: java, interface, hierarchy

This is for learning. I have an interface that is implemented by 2 classes, and I am supposed to reduce the amount of code I use in order to keep things more clean and less messy. Currently, the code looks like this:

```
public abstract class VClass implements IntFace {

  protected String name;

  public VClass(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int value (SClass sc) {//comes from a diff class
    return sc.lookup(name);
  }

  public String getName() {
   return name; 
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
   return getName(); 
  }
}

public abstract class NClass extends VClass implements IntFace {

  public Number(String name) {
   super(name);
     this.name = name;
  }

  public int value (SClass sc) {
    return sc.lookup(name);
  }

  public String getName() {
   return name; 
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
   return getName(); 
  }
}

public interface IntFace {

  public int value (SClass sc);

  public String toString (int num);
}
```

can this code be more condensed?

Comment: "I know that they don't have return types.". Methods have return types. Since you don't know much, I suggest you start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). It's a lot better resource for learning than whatever you're doing here.

Comment: Hi thanks, I'm just looking to see how much I can condense my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the following things from your code:

1. `implements IntFace` from `NClass` declaration. Since `NClass extends VClass`, it implements `IntFace` as well.
2. `this.name = name;` from `NClass` constructor. `name` is initialized in a superclass constructor
3. `value` and `getName` methods from `NClass`. These methods are implemented in a superclass.
4. `public` modifier from interface methods declaration. Methods in interfaces are `public` by default.

Now you can also make `name` field `private` since it's no longer used in a `NClass`.